# Laravel scope comparing two related model attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application, there's a "Transaction" model, a "Concept" model, and an "Account" model. Each $transaction belongs to both a $concept and an $origin_account. I need to design a scope() in the Transaction::class capable of retrieving those transactions paid by an entity different from the intended original entity for reimbursement purposes. Ideally, I should be able to do this:

```
public function scopeCrossed($query) {
    return $query->where($this->origin_account->entity_id, '<>', $this->concept->entity_id);
}
```

Of course, the above code doesn't work, but how would you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `whereHas` clause to your query to add a constraint on the `concept` relationship. Here's how you can modify your `scopeCrossed` method:

```php
public function scopeCrossed($query) {
    return $query->whereHas('origin_account', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('concept', function ($query) {
            $query->whereColumn('origin_accounts.entity_id', '<>', 'concepts.entity_id');
        });
    });
}
```

In the above code, the inner `whereHas` method adds a constraint on the `concept` relationship of the `origin_account`. The `whereColumn` method is used to compare the `entity_id` column of the `origin_account` with the `entity_id` column of the `concept`. This will return the transactions where the `entity_id` of the `origin_account` is not equal to the `entity_id` of the `concept`.

Comment: Thanks, @Karl Hill, but this solution only takes me half way, since you are comparing $account->entidad_id to transactions.concept_id, but I need to compare against $transaction->concept->entity_id.